# Trying to pass POST from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

For a few days now I have been trying to pass a simple POST call to a php script from JavaScript. I've done countless amounts of searching online without any positive results.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function successHandler(location) {
    var dataString = '?lat=' + location.coords.latitude + '&long=' + location.coords.longitude + '&accuracy=' + location.coords.accuracy;
    alert(dataString);
    if (location.coords.latitude == '0') {
    } else {
        alert("AJAX made");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatepos.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler),15000);
    }
}

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler);
}

getLocation();

</script>
```

Above is my JavaScript file. The datastring gets made, and it alerts it out to my browser. No problem there. The problem is, my variables don't get passed to PHP whatsoever.

Here is the PHP that is in the same directory as the JavaScript.

```
<?php
include 'wp-load.php';
/*global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo $current_user->user_login;*/

include('dbconnect.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$long = $_POST['long'];
$accuracy = $_POST['accuracy'];
/*$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$long = $_GET['long'];
$accuracy = $_GET['accuracy'];*/
$query = "UPDATE ltc_users SET lat='$lat',accuracy=$accuracy,lon='$long' WHERE name='$current_user->user_login'";
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['DB'],$query);
echo mysqli_error($GLOBALS['DB']);
echo $lat;
echo $long;
echo $accuracy;
echo $current_user->user_login;
?>
```

I may note that before the script would return mysql syntax errors as it was echoed in php due to missing variables. The syntax works if I use the $_GET method and just type in the data into my browser address bar for testing. It just doesn't get the JavaScript variables for whatever reason.

Comment: try passing data in the correct format, as an object. creating a querystring yourself is shaky as hell, and is considered the incorrect method since jQuery 1.7

Comment: Just a quick thought, could be wrong, but try taking out the question mark from the beginning of your data string.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a string to jquery. When you do that, the string is sent out as-is by jquery. Since it's just a bare string, and not a key:value pair, there's no key for PHP to glom onto and populate $_POST with.

In fact, you shouldn't ever have to manually build a string of key:value pairs for ajax - jquery will take an array/object and do it all for you:

```
var stuff = {
    lat : location.coords.latitude,
    long : location.coords.longitude,
    accuracy : location.coords.accuracy
}

$.ajax({
   data: stuff
});
```

Comment: jQuery ajax documentations: `data Type: PlainObject or String or Array`

Comment: yes, and if you pass in a plain string, then you need to have `data: {foo: yourstring}`, which will show up as `$_POST['foo']`. OP has no key, just a bare string, so there's nothing in $_POST. The data could probably be retrieve from php://input, and then decoded manually.

Comment: You're making a post, not a get request.  In a get request you may want your dataString to be formatted similar to how it is, but a post request sends the actual string or object, not url parameters.

Comment: @Marc B nope. `var datastring = "param1=value1&param2=value2";` is also good, and it will be param1 and param2 value in the `$_POST`

Comment: Yes, and do not need that. Let's try it yourself.

Comment: I have tried this method among the one below. I have replaced my dataString var with the object version instead but to no avail I'm afraid. I'm not sure what the problem could be at all.

Comment: I have tried this method among the one below. I have replaced my dataString var with the object version instead but to no avail I'm afraid. I'm not sure what the problem could be at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code combined with @Marc B

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function successHandler(location) {

    if (location.coords.latitude == '0') {
    } else {
        alert("AJAX made ");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatepos.php",
            data: {
              "lat":location.coords.latitude,
              "long":location.coords.longitude,
              "accuracy":location.coords.accuracy
            },
            dataType: "json",
            async:true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            },error: function(a,b,c){
                console.log(a.responseText);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler);},15000);
    }
}

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler);
}
$(function(){
  getLocation();
});

</script>
```

code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y7f1vkej/ it seems to be working for me

Comment: Hi, after trying this I still have not had success. I'm still not quite sure what the problem is. I haven't changed the PHP script yet, other than changing the POST to GET and trying it with the browser address line to confirm that the SQL still works, and it does. It appears as if the variables just won't get passed in. I was able to echo the SQL error and I don't see any variables where text should be.

Comment: Nothing shows. No error no success. I'm using Firebug

Comment: are you getting the AJAX made alert? is there any error showing up in console.

Comment: Nothing is shown in console. AJAX made alert comes up. Success alert does not show

Comment: pls try the code now, there was a formatting issue in the earlier code

Comment: Tried that. Even tried making a complete new script as a test. No dice.

Comment: I got it working. I had to change some variable names around and it worked. Thanks.